# Is it good practice to return references to iterators? (Does it even make sense)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, objective-c++

I'm not sure if this is a legit thing to do here - Returning an iterator by reference:

1. vector::iterator& getElement(const char* name) {...}

note that my vector holds the **elements themselves** and **not pointers**.

At the current state, I've left it by value (without &).

Is there a consensus regarding iterators or can I use both ways?

Comment: how does this relate to objective-c++?

Answer (score 3):

What would be the point? iterator is in-and-of-itself a kind of reference to something inside the vector. Are you looking to give someone an iterator that you might modify internally? That is, the class handing out the reference to an iterator itself increments it -- points it to another thing in the vector -- and the client somehow has its iterator pointing to the right thing cause it called getElement() before? That's the only application of references to iterators I can think of and it definitely smells bad too me.

But more importantly, there's serious issues with exposing and therefore possibly persisting iterators. Iterators become invalid. If you have an iterator to something internal in your interface, and something deletes or adds to the vector, you won't be able to guarantee the client's iterators are still valid. Then the client accesses their invalid iterator and undefined behavior -- ie a CRASH -- happens.

Comment: This could be used for things like linked list, the list will advance iterators that get invalid because of erase automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a parameter by reference only makes sense if the iterator is "owned" by another object and you want the caller to modify the owner's iterator.  Which 99% of the time is a bad idea.  Generally, an iterator should be treated like a pointer, and a pointer is pretty much always returned/passed by value except for oddball cases.

Comment: Actually: In general, return by value, unless you _need_ a reference.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a universal sentiment for general C++ programming. Many argue you should make things non-copyable by default and return by const reference. The argument goes its safer to not have to worry about your object and everything it aggregates being able to copy itself correctly.

Comment: Hmm, I disagree with that, because that requires the parent object to instantiate and hold onto the object being returned.  With vector::end() and vector::size(), most implementations won't have a corresponding member for both, so one must be a return by value.  Also, all C++ objects should be safe or impossible to copy IMO.